# Can Magento 2 Functional Test Framework run inside a Vagrant box?

Tags: magento2, testing, ftf, selenium

I'm trying to run the Magento 2 Functional Testing Framework (FTF) inside a Vagrant box, but without success.

My setup is a host machine, which runs Selenium and a Vagrant box which runs Magento 2. What I'm currently doing:

- I'm running Selenium in hub mode on my host machine:
  `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar -role hub -port 5555`
- In my guest machine, I'm also running selenium, but as a node (which connects to the hub on my host):
  `java -jar /vagrant/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.56.1:5555/grid/register -port 4444`

The connection is established, and I see activity in both console windows that they're connected.

But... as soon as I try the out-of-the box functional tests that come bundled with Magento 2, I get the following error in as well PHP as Selenium (node):

```
Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
```

Needless to say, I don't have Firefox installed in my Vagrant box. It is however installed on my host machine (together with some other selenium driven browsers, like Chrome and Safari).

But the fact that I get this error makes me wonder: is the FTF capable of running it's test in a setup like this? Or is it really intended to run native on a system? Or am I perhaps overseeing a simple configuration here?

**EDIT:**

Here are some more details about my setup:

- I'm using Vagrant 1.9.1, Virtualbox 5.1.14 and Selenium standalone server 3.0.0-beta3.
- The forwarded ports are 8080 -> 80, 8443 -> 443, 8025 -> 8025. Note that I don't forward port 4444 nor 5555 (If I'm not mistaken this is not necessary due to the direction of the traffic).
- The IP address of my host machine (eth0) is 10.31.40.176
- My vagrant is setup as a private network on IP 192.168.56.101
- The IP address of my guest machine (eth0) is 10.0.2.15
- On my host machine, I run selenium as a hub on port 5555. The hub shows `Nodes should register to http://10.31.40.176:5555/grid/register/`.
- On my guest machine, I run selenium as a node on port 4444. I register it to the hub on `http://10.31.40.176:5555/grid/register`. Both the node as the hub state that they're connected:

node:

```
07:57:19.092 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://10.31.40.176:5555/grid/register
07:57:19.110 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

hub:

```
08:59:29.590 INFO - Registered a node http://192.168.56.101:4444
08:59:29.590 WARN - Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node http://192.168.56.101:4444
```

- I've edited my `etc/config.xml`-file and added the following parameters after `</install>`:

XML:

```
<server>
    <item name="selenium"
          type="default"
          browser="Mozilla Firefox"
          browserName="firefox"
          host="10.0.2.15"
          port="4444"
          seleniumServerRequestsTimeout="90"
          sessionStrategy="shared">
        <desiredCapabilities>
            <platform>ANY</platform>
        </desiredCapabilities>
    </item>
</server>
```

Now when I run the built-in PHPUnit with FTF, I still get the error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
Build info: version: '3.0.0-beta3', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:57:03 -0700'
System info: host: 'magento2', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver in /var/www/public/dev/tests/functional/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Driver.php:165
```

I know that the configuration is read, because when I change `browser` and `browserName` to `Google Chrome` and `chrome` I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html in /var/www/public/dev/tests/functional/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Driver.php:165
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run functional tests inside Vagrant box. You need to follow this guide http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/mtf/mtf_quickstart.html for configuring environment.

Note, that selenium with specific browser driver must to be run on host machine, but on guest machine you need to set host machine ip *(10.0.0.2 for example)* as `host` in `config.xml` file.

```
<server>
<item name="selenium"
      type="default"
      browser="Google Chrome"
      browserName="chrome"
      host="{{HOST_MACHINE_IP}}"
      port="4444"
      seleniumServerRequestsTimeout="90"
      sessionStrategy="shared">
    <desiredCapabilities>
        <platform>ANY</platform>
    </desiredCapabilities>
</item>
</server>
```

Additionally, you can use headless running of functiona tests on guest machine, using `xvfb` (on CI server for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I keep getting the error message (`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX`). I'll improve my question with further details, perhaps you can help me.

Comment: Are you run selenium on host machine or guest?

Comment: I run Selenium on host as a hub, and on guest as a node.

Comment: you need to run selenium only on host machine as described in documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/mtf/mtf_quickstart/mtf_quickstart_environment.html. On the guest machine you need to run functional tests (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/mtf/mtf_quickstart/mtf_quickstart_runtest.html), which will connect to selenium on host machine, using `config.xml` `host` configuration

Comment: Thanks! It works now! I have selenium running on my host machine, and I configured my guest to use 192.168.56.1 on port 4444. Which is strange, because my private network IP is 192.168.56.101 and not .1, but hey... it works. Any thoughts on why I have to use .1 in my guest instead of .101?

Comment: Cool! You can use `ifconfig` (Linux) or `ipconfig` (Windows) for getting ip of host machine. I have updated my answer with info about headless running mode.